# Is building a CPU-intensive C# application for use on Linux (via. Mono) a bad idea?

Tags: c#, linux, performance, mono

I guess what I'm asking is running my application under Mono going to be notably bad for performance?  Note that the application is not meant to do or require anything other than access to a local relational database (probably MySQL).

Edit: The application is meant to do in-memory work with data queried from the database. The database itself should not be a bottleneck.

Also, the 'work' will be multi-threaded and (must be anticipated to be) as much "parallel" as "serial", if that makes sense...

Edit 2: Profiling hasn't yet been done as the product is only now coming out of a long planning phase to begin development, but the plan was made with anticipation of likely use making this mostly memory-intensive by design (so as to eventually allow the database itself to be made to do as much work as possible, ideally). However, cases of "serial" work (i.e. number crunching) must be expected to occur by design, but my goal is to eliminate these cases as much as possible.

Edit 3: By number crunching, I mean literally any math formula serialized into the database and called into use for representing some kind of abstract data.  Most of my (eventual) work will be to minimize this, however.

Comment: There is no fundamental reason to assume "mono is slow"; if you want to know how it performs for a *particular operation*, versus say native (via C++) and/or java/jvm, then you'll need to write all 3 and compare all 3 on the same hardware...

Comment: Will the CPU-intensive operations be performed in your code, or handled by MySQL?

Comment: Writing or porting the application may not be trivial. I'm currently relegated to Linux machines for my web hosting, by incidence.

Comment: @LarsKristensen Code. Any CPU load from the database will be easy to optimize.

Comment: And why do you expect the load to be CPU-intensive instead of, say, memory-intensive? I gather it's not a number crunching kind of load.

Comment: I meant, memory throughput is usually a major bottleneck for a type of code you're describing. Have you already done any profiling?

Comment: @SK-logic Let me restate that: Memory-intensive, mainly, but the input data *could* specify lots of number crunching. My goal is to design to avoid those cases, but some scenarios could make that difficult..

Comment: If there is a lot of number crunching involved, please specify, what kind of number crunching. Mono has SIMD intrinsics, for example, so certain types of numeric applications can be very efficient. Pure memory-bound things are normally performing on par with, say, C++ implementations, as long as you're not abusing GC too much.

Comment: @SK-logic I'll update my post with information to answer this shortly.

Comment: With your update, .NET now looks like the best option available: it's perfect for dynamic code generation, so you can get very efficient implementations for expressions and algorithms stored in your database in runtime. Otherwise you'd have to resort to interpretation, which is likely to be too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question indicates that you assume that Mono is some kind of .NET *emulation*, like wine is a Win32 emulation. This is *not* the case.
Mono is a native implementation of the .NET framework, so there is no reason why it should be fundamentally and/or generally slower than the implementation of the .NET framework on Windows.

Answer (score -3):

It is a bad idea. I ported my application to mono and it doesn't work well:
1. Mono is not stable when it comes to threads (try to load many threads and see how it goes down)
2. Mono does not behave as expected with Forms
3. You are building CPU intensive app and Mono is very slow (as well as .NET) so use cpp, Python or something else.

Comment: Do you really believe Python implementations are faster with number crunching stuff than Mono?!? Not to mention that the rest of your post is also full of lies.

Comment: -1: This is [anecdotal evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdotal_evidence) at best and with all hard facts missing it is actually not an answer at all but simply a rant.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I've heard comments like these for years, hence my concern and question. C++ seems a bit off-putting for what I'm trying to do, otherwise I'd have since simply taken advice like this a while ago...

Comment: @Hamster: Those comments shouldn't be taken too seriously, especially if real examples are missing. Most of the time, they are from people that simply dislike .NET in general or that are using it incorrectly.

Comment: @Avia, I recommend you to use the `--server` flag when using Mono in your threading scenario